# How to only display 10 <li> items in a <ul> with php

Tags: php, html, css, tcpdf

I have a problem using tcpdf. A form on my page sends a post variable containing content with `<li></li>` items.

```
$fzg_features = '<li>' . $_POST['fzg-features'] . '</li>';
```

I was able to count all `<li>` items but i only want to display item 1-10.
Is it possible to index the `<li>` items with php and manage the output? e.g. 4-6 of all list items?

The problem is the source of `$_POST['fzg-features']`. It comes from a wp plugin writing the whole content as `<li></li> items` in an array key as a single string.

Comment: can you actually print $_POST so we'll see it's structure

Comment: Be careful about printing `$_POST` data directly back into your HTML code; eg if the user entered a `<` character, it will break your HTML (this can also be used for hacking it). You should always escape your input. In this case, use `htmlentities()` to make it safe to display.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. A good way to learn here.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes as single string you can explode `</li>` and then remove `<li>`.

```
$pizza  = "<li>example</li><li>another example</li>"; // Example string
$pieces = explode("</li>", $pizza); // Make many small pieces
foreach ($pieces as $key => $piece) { // Go through all pieces
 if ($key === 9) break; // First key in array is 0, so we limit it to 9.
 echo substr($piece, 2); // Remove first 2 characters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Great, I stand in your debt. Works fine for me. My main issue was to calculate columns for displaying Car features in tcpdf as a 3 column list. As it is not possible using css this solution worked for me:

```
$fzg_features = $_POST['fzg-features'];
// $pieces holds the array
$pieces = explode("</li><li>", $fzg_features); // Make many small pieces
foreach ($pieces as $key => $piece) { // Go through all pieces
}

// column calculation
$columns = 3;
$colamount = count($pieces) / $columns;
$colamount1 = ceil($colamount);
$colamount2 = ceil($colamount)*2;

// first column
for ($i = 0; $i <= $colamount1 -1; $i++){
    echo '<li>' . $pieces[$i] . '</li>';
    };
echo '<br><br>';
// second column
for ($i = $colamount1; $i <= $colamount2 -1; $i++){
    echo '<li>' . $pieces[$i] . '</li>';
    };
echo '<br><br>';
// third column
for($i = $colamount2; $i <= count($pieces)-1; $i++){
    echo '<li>' . $pieces[$i] . '</li>';
    };
```

Thanks a lot for your help.